# .NET MVC 3: How to hide parameters in a RedirectToAction GET Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to parameterise a get method in .NET MVC3.
Suppose I have a get method (simplified):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Message(string message)
{
    ...
    return View(message);
}
```

And a post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething() 
{
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("Message", new { message = ok ? "Done it" : "Nope" });
}
```

The reason for this is that I might have lots of different messages dynamically generated from various different Post methods and I want to display them in a common View. The Message View is also quite complicated so I want to avoid repeating code. Parameterising the Message Action is really the perfect solution.

This works fine, apart from one thing: The message string is always present in the URL, and this doesn't look very good to the user. Also there are potential problems with max URL length etc.

eg. http://www.domain.com/Controller/Message?message=Nope

What I really want is to return from the Get method the Message page with the correct message, but then also have the URL just read: http://www.domain.com/Controller/Message

Any ideas anyone?
Thanks

Comment: GET parameters are always displayed in the URL. You will have to use a different persistence mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the message in the `Session`, then remove it from the session in the message action.

Answer (score 2):

As SLaks said the message can be stored server-side, but `Controller.TempData` is better suited for this than `Session`.

Comment: I think Controller will be recreated with temp data

Comment: Agreed this would work, but code-wise this is a messy approach in my opinion. I have since experimented with MVC Contrib PassParametersDuringRedirect which is basically the kind of solution that I am looking for. However this still appears to pass strings via the url which just "looks" messy

Answer (score 1):

Why are you redirecting to the action?  Why not just render that view in line.  If you need to run specific code, you could even have a base controller that implements it and inherit from it so you don't repeat yourself.  Note: you can keep the `Message` view in the Shared views folder so it can be found for any controller.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult MessageView(string message)
     {
         ... some common logging functions or such...

         return View("Message",message);
     }
}
```

Called as

```
public class FooController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoSomething() 
    {
        ...
        return MessageView( ok ? "Done it" : "Nope" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work because this controller doesn't have a view associated with it, hence one of the reasons I wish to use the Message View

Comment: @chris did you see my note about putting the message view in the shared folder where it could be used by all controllers/actions?  I think this is more idiomatic that what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's not that I can't use the MessageView - that's not a problem. The point is that this would render MessageView in /FooController/DoSomething which is not what I want. I want to completely redirect to /FooController/MessageView. I just want to be able to pass parameters to this easily. The nearest thing I have found so far is MVC Contrib PassParametersDuringRedirect, which mostly does what I want

Answer (score 0):

Another viable solution apart from Controller.TempData would be the use of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is a cookie. This approach will help you to save RESTfulness of your application. I mean no server saved data